# SQL SELECT what in range number

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help to solve my issue.

I have a table like this one,

```
id | Desc | Min Range | Max Range
-----------------------------------
1  |  A   |     0     |    10
2  |  B   |     11    |    20
3  |  C   |     21    |    30
```

How to get the second record when I put parameter 20.

My solution now is like this:

```
select * from table where maxRange <= 20
```

and in java, I get last of result list.

My problem is I don't have parameter to compare when I use between. eg.

```
select * from table where maxRange between ? and ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from table where ? between minrange and maxrange
```

Comment: thank you, its work like a charm.. i never know that my parameter can be use like that.. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the parameter to you command when you query.

Create a Parameter called @Parameter with value 20 - this is dependant on what technology you are using. Then:

> SELECT * FROM table  WHERE @Parameter >= MinRange AND @Parmeter <=
>   MaxRange